# LM317 current regulation below 20mA

Tags: linear-regulator

I made small regulator which is supposed to deliver from 20 mA to the exact lower limit of LM317 for current regulation in self-biased mode.

The question is, the [LM317 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) says it's rated 10 mA minimum with no deviation tables. Then is it possible to achieve a round 10 mA limit, is that limit a bit flexible or should I be looking for other round number let's say 20, so my calculations are simplified rather than using 12 mA for an instance for a ESR measurement or whatever I'm driving through.

If it does 10 mA round current regulation, can I expect some resistive behavior in some lower limits? Can I find information about these tables?

Answer (score 2):

The LM317 is specified to maintain output voltage regulation with loads of 10 mA or more, but will typically maintain regulation with loads as low as 3.5 mA.

The minimum load current is not a single fixed value - it can vary between devices.